# How do I attach a sticky element exactly to the side of my main wrapper

Tags: css, screen

I want to attach a sticky element(containing social media icons) to the right of my main wrapper which has a width of 960px and not stuck to the right side of the screen.

Any simple CSS ways of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean like position fixed only constrained to a div?

Answer (score 1):

```
div#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
div#socialmediaicons {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="socialmediaicons"> ... </div>
</div>
```

"Absolutely" positioned elements will be positioned with respect to the closest parent element that is itself positioned.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer works for you, please click the check mark on the left to accept this as the correct answer. That will help my reputation score, and encourage others to answer your questions in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good jQuery plugin for this very need:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/stickyfloat

Tt gives you powers beyond mere CSS.